# class to calculate area of sphere Python

Tags: python, geometry

I was looking at a code to calculate area of sphere and I noticed they used _ *eq* _. I know it's used to check equality, but I am wondering what is the need for it in this example?

```
class Point3d:
......

    def distance_from_origin(self):
        temp_x = self.x ** 2
        temp_y = self.y ** 2
        temp_z = self.z ** 2
        return ((temp_x) + (temp_y) + (temp_z)) ** 0.5 

    def area_of_sphere(self):
        return (4 * math.pi * (self.distance_from_origin())**2)

    def __eq__(self, object):
        if self.x == object.x and self.y == object.y and self.z == object.z:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.x) + " , " + str(self.y) + " , " + str(self.z)
```

Comment: Well, it is nice to have a method to see if 2 points in a 3D space are the same.

Comment: that explains it. thank you for the clarification

Comment: At some moment, this implementation of `__eq__` will fail for floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `area_of_sphere` should not be there at all. That goes against the whole idea of having a class.

The `Point.__eq__` method works so that you can write

```
p1 = Point(...)
p2 = Point(...)

if p1 == p2: ...
```

otherwise, the default behavior of `==` would be to check if they are the same object, and it would return false.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a requirement of a uniform API, which systematically includes an equality operator as well as a string formatter.

They are of strictly no use to compute the area. One may even question if a class is needed at all for such an elementary formula. (By the way, there is a sad loss of efficiency caused by the fact that you take a square root then square back.)